# How long should I wait before starting an image just pushed to bluemix

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud

I have a script to push an image to bluemix and start the container right after the push.

```
 docker push xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 cf ic group create xxxxxxxxxxx
```

Sometimes I got an error saying the image is not found. However, if i do a `cf ic images| grep MY_IMAGE:VERSION` I can find my image there!

I am guessing this is because I try to start the container too quick? If so, how long I should wait before I can run cf ic group create?

Answer (score 1):

I would first double check to make sure that your script is specifying the image's tag explicitly, like "myimage:latest". And make sure that the immagename:tag is consistent both during the docker push and also during the subsequent group create. Hope this is helpful!

Comment: I am pretty sure my script specify the tag and it is consistent. I run my script couple of times per day. Sometimes, it works without any problem. Sometimes I got error messages. However, if I run my script again, it is all good. So I am wondering if I need to wait for a certain time before I can start my image?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you haven't to wait a time interval before starting/running an image remotely once uploaded: have you ever tried waiting and running after some time with the same failing image and it worked fine?
I am suspecting that when you got an error starting an image you are not correctly referring it using the name:tag parameter. If you wish you can provide the full list of the steps followed when running an image fails (be also sure to run within the same terminal to avoid session problems)